# Prevent childs to inherit parent's opacity

Tags: html, css

I want light blue background for body and pure red div on it.
somehow body opacity effecting my content div opacity,so am not getting pure red div,but 
instead am getting  opacity red.

```
<html>
   <title>............Generic............</title>
   <head>
      <style>
         #myContent {
         position:relative;
         background: blue;
         height:630px;
         width:1080px;
         left:150px;
         right:50px;

         border-radius:4px;
         }

        #header {
        position:relative;
        left:-10px;
        right:30px;
        top:50px;
        background: red;
        width:600px;
        height:100px;


        }

        #myContent:not(#header) {
        opacity:0.1;
        }


      </style>
      <script></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="myFun()">
      <div id="myContent">
        <div id="header">
        </div>

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `opacity: 1` to the #header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using both `backgroung-color` and `opacity` just use a RGB background color.

Add `background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.1);` to `#myContent` and remove `#myContent:not(#header)` totally.

**[Check Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ay8jj9u5/)**